# Trying to build up a internal application load balancer using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have started using Terraforms just recently. I am trying to create a internal load balancer using terraforms. Can someone guide me how to do it because when I am running the terraform script it throws me an erro stating internal load balancer needs to be created inside a VPC. I get it because internal load balancer will have a private subnet. How do  I provide the VPC id while creating the Internal Load Balancer ?

```
provider "aws" {
region = "ap-south-1"
}

module "vpc" {
 source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

   provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-south-1"
  }

  module "vpc" {
   source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

   name = "my-vpc"
   cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"

   azs             = ["ap-south-1a", "ap-south-1b"]
   private_subnets = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24"]

   enable_nat_gateway = true
   enable_vpn_gateway = true

   tags = {
     Terraform = "true"
     Environment = "dev"
   }
  }

  resource "aws_elb" "bar" {
   name               = "foobar-terraform-elb"
   availability_zones = ["ap-south-1"]
   internal = true

   access_logs {
     bucket        = "foo"
     bucket_prefix = "bar"
     interval      = 60
   }

   listener {
     instance_port     = 8000
     instance_protocol = "http"
     lb_port           = 80
     lb_protocol       = "http"
   }

   listener {
     instance_port      = 8000
     instance_protocol  = "http"
     lb_port            = 443
     lb_protocol        = "https"
     ssl_certificate_id = "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:server-certificate/certName"
   }

   health_check {
     healthy_threshold   = 2
     unhealthy_threshold = 2
     timeout             = 3
     target              = "HTTP:8000/"
     interval            = 30
   }

   instances                   = ["i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
   cross_zone_load_balancing   = true
   idle_timeout                = 400
   connection_draining         = true
   connection_draining_timeout = 400

   tags = {
     Name = "foobar-terraform-elb"
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`subnets`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elb.html#subnets) parameter provided by Terraform to create an internal load balancer.

In your case it could be

```
resource "aws_elb" "bar" {
   ...
   subnets = "${module.vpc.private_subnets}"
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Private subnets are part of a VPC and terraform expects list of subnets for creating an ELB in VPC.
Refer: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elb.html#subnets

you can update your `aws_elb` code as

```
resource "aws_elb" "bar" {
   name               = "foobar-terraform-elb"
   subnets = ["subnet-1-id"]

   # If you need multiple subnets then provide value as follow
   # subnets = ["subnet-1-id", "subnet-2-id"]

   internal = true

   access_logs {
     bucket        = "foo"
     bucket_prefix = "bar"
     interval      = 60
   }

   listener {
     instance_port     = 8000
     instance_protocol = "http"
     lb_port           = 80
     lb_protocol       = "http"
   }

   listener {
     instance_port      = 8000
     instance_protocol  = "http"
     lb_port            = 443
     lb_protocol        = "https"
     ssl_certificate_id = "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:server-certificate/certName"
   }

   health_check {
     healthy_threshold   = 2
     unhealthy_threshold = 2
     timeout             = 3
     target              = "HTTP:8000/"
     interval            = 30
   }

   instances                   = ["i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
   cross_zone_load_balancing   = true
   idle_timeout                = 400
   connection_draining         = true
   connection_draining_timeout = 400

   tags = {
     Name = "foobar-terraform-elb"
   }
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks man. It works quite a bit but now it gives me an error in the `ssl_certificate_id` part. The error is **Error creating ELB Listener with SSL Cert, retrying: CertificateNotFound: Server Certificate not found for the key: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:server-certificate/certName** Any idea on how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you double check you have a certificate with this ARN (arn:aws:iam::123456789012:server-certificate/certName) ?

Comment: Thanks dude. I checked and I found that I have no certificate present. How do I do it then ?

Comment: this may help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_server-certs.html

Comment: Cool. I'll take a look. Thanks.